# Nested Geometric Series Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

I would like to derive a general formula for series of the following type:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{1}{A^n}\right) + \sum_{j=n}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{A^n\cdot B^j}\right)\right)$$

I attempted first to decompose it into parts by considering the nested loop:

$$n=1$$

$$\frac{1}{A}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{B^j}\right)$$

which then allows for $n=1$ to be defined as:

$$\frac{1}{A} * \left(\frac{\frac{1}{B}}{1-\frac{1}{B}}\right)$$

then, letting $n$ iterate:

$$\frac{1}{A},\frac{1}{A^2},\frac{1}{A^3},...,\frac{1}{A^n},...$$

However, I'm having difficulty finding a rewrite for this nested loop. If one does exist, how would I extend that if I had a triply nested loop and so on. Thanks!

Comment: In your second set of equations, you need to have the A inside the summation (as the power depends on j) and the B outside (as its power doesn't depend on j). Also $\sum_n a_n b_n \neq (\sum a_n)(\sum_n b_n)$ generally so your second-last expression is wrong...

Comment: @theindigamer You're right my mistake. I'll fix the first problem, and I just realized that step is also wrong like you said. Do you have any ideas on how to rewrite that series?

Comment: Oh, you changed the first equation! Are the powers correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore the outer summation for now and first just simplify the inner sum.

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{A^n B^j} = \frac{1}{A^n}\sum_{j=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{B^j} = \frac{1}{A^n B^n}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{B^j} = \frac{1}{A^n B^n}\frac{1}{1-1/B}
\end{align}
Notice that the power of $A$ doesn't depend on $j$, so the $A$ term can hop outside the sum. After that, we factored out the first term for convenience. Finally, we applied the standard geometric series formula with common ratio $1/B$.

Now let's get back to the outer sum
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{A^n} + \frac{1}{(AB)^n}\frac{1}{1-1/B} 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{A^n} + \frac{1}{1-1/B}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(AB)^n}
\end{align}
We've split the sum over the two terms and we took the $1/(1-1/B)$ out of the summation because it doesn't depend on $n$. I think from this point, you will be able to finish the problem.

> However, I'm having difficulty finding a rewrite for this nested loop. If one does exist, how would I extend that if I had a triply nested loop and so on.

In this case, as you can see it is easier to not work with individual terms but to keep the indices (instead of plugging them in immediately) and try to simplify. Plugging in indices, then writing the sequence, and then creating indices again by spotting the pattern is more prone to error and I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: Thanks, I can definitely finish the problem now! I should have thought a bit longer and noticed that. I can see how to extend it to 3 terms and so on now too!